# Determinate update time

Tags: php, javascript, html

As I'm currently in the process of making a forum system which is loading new posts/edits without having to refresh the page. Now, for the older browers which don't have an implentation of EventSource/WebSocket, I'd like to offer another option:

Every X seconds I'm GET'ing a PHP site which is echoing the five latest news. Afterwards, I'm simply checking which of those news weren't seen by the client yet and applying the changes to the page.

Now, my problem is: How would you determinate the X interval in which the client is retrieving new updates? I'd like to base it up the user's connections so that it isn't killing off his connection completely.

What would be your attempt at accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) technique through `AJAX` in your case:

1) The client sends the AJAX HTTP-request to the server.

2) If there is an available data, server sends HTTP-request to client, otherwise instead of  sending an empty response immediately, server holds the request and waits for information to become available (or for a suitable timeout event - for example, in every 25 seconds), after which a complete response is finally sent to the client.

3) After recieving the HTTP-respose, client immediately sends other HTTP-request to server.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @AleksG I've added more details

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following (code not tested, but you should get the idea). Use jQuery for simpler code.

```
function refreshNews() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax-url"
    }).done(function(data){
        /** add code here */
        setTimeout(function(){ refreshNews(); }, 30000); // 30 secs should be enough to read some headlines
    });
}
refreshNews();
```

This way the `refreshNews()` function is only called after the data is received and shown to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: make a HTTP request and see how much it will take long and use it as the base! I'd repeat it, let say each 10 minutes to show how much I'm thinking about my clients!

I think it will be more resource-friendly on the server-side comparing to the `long polling`, especially for scripts like forums where people won't left the page for less than 10 hours. :)